# "Global" service in Angular 4 (to save API calls)

Tags: angular, observable

Sorry if the title doesn't match what I mean. I'll try to explain what I'd like to do and perhaps someone can tell me a better alternative:

I want to create a service that gets data from a database and stores it internally so it doesn't need to call the API any more. For example, I want the service to get the details of some objects; the first call to the service must get the data through the API, and stores it inside. So, when I call the service again from other components, it won't make a call to the API but it will return the stored data, reducing dramatically the need for API calls. Is this possible?

I tried this but it doesn't work, it always makes a call to the API:

**(EDITED: FULL SERVICE CLASS CODE)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ObjectService {

  // We'll store the objects in this array
  private savedObjects : any;
  private objSubject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getObjects() : Observable<any> {

    const url = `http://URL_TO_API/objects`;

    if(!this.savedObjects || !this.savedObjects.length) {
      // We don't have any saved objects yet, make API call
      console.log("Getting the objects through API call");

      return this.http.get(url)
       .map(this.extractData) // Basically returns a JSON
       .map((objs) => { this.savedObjects = objs; return objs; } ) 
       .catch(this.handleError)
      ;
    }
    else {
      // Don't need to call the API
      console.log(["No API", this.savedObjects]);

      this.objSubject.next(this.savedObjects);

      return this.objSubject.asObservable();
    }
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    //console.log("RECEIVED DATA: " + res.text());
    let body = res.json();

    return body || {};
  }


  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

I provide the service only in AppComponent, but I think it doesn't mean that it's 'global' for all the components... (I'm still learning Angular 4, so there are things I don't fully understand).

**EDITED:**
I've provided the service only in the AppModule file but nothing happens.

The way I use this service from other components is:

```
(...)
import { ObjectService } from '../../services/object.service';

(...)

@Component({
  selector: 'app-target-container',
  templateUrl: './app-target-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-target-container.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: []
})
export class AppTargetContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(protected objectService : ObjectService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Get the objects
    this.objectService.getObjects().subscribe((objects: any) => {
        console.log(['Read objects: ', objects]);
        this.processObjects(objects);
    });

  }

  processObjects(objects : any) {
    // DO STUFF
  }
}
```

I've been reading some docs on ReplaySubject but I can't figure out how to use them for what I need... Can anyone recommend a good tutorial or book?

How could I do this? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try providing it **only** in your AppModule's providers array rather than AppComponent. Also do you have any lazy-loaded modules?

Comment: Can you write more of your service class? and *where* and *how* are you use it?

Answer (score 0):

Add your API service to providers of your AppModule.

The simplest caching is to save API route, request params and responses (e. g. in a ReplaySubject) and return previously executed requests' responses.

If your API is written in Graphql, I'd recommend Apollo which includes API caching.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I'm interested in the caching method you mentioned that uses ReplaySubject but I can't find any good resource to learn. Can you recommend me one? Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Double checking the code, I realized that I had provided the service in a sibling component for doing some tests and I forgot to remove it later, so Angular created a new instance of the service and that's the reason the data wasn't persistent!

So, providing the ObjectService in AppCömponent (or AppModule) ONLY ONCE, it works perfectly.

Sorry about the lapse :)

Comment: So does this means that we can not use service in other component? In your case, can't we use ` // Get the objects` block in other component to get same data in other component without calling same api again?

Comment: Hi! The service can be used from any component, but, to avoid the unnecessary calls to the API, you need to provide it only once so it shares a single instance across the application.